# How to include proj4js into your project

Tags: javascript, html, proj4js

I really don't understand how to include the proj4.js into my project. Following the documentation I should add

```
<script src="lib/proj4js-combined.js"></script>
```

in the code. But if I add it into the .html file my .js file (in which I will use the proj4js functions) will not see it. And I can not add it into my .js file as it is a .js file and not an .html file..
How did you do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just load them in order (in your html file):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="lib/proj4js-combined.js"></script>
        <script src="myfolder/js-file-with-proj4js-functions.js"></script>
    </head> 
<body>
    ...
```

Then your js file will be able to see everything it needs from the library.

Comment: @ayasha why don't you create it or download it from where you saw it?

Comment: I found a complete version.. I have now included both proj4js-combined.js and proj4js.js, now it sees everything apart the Proj4js.trasform function for which it says its not a function.. but that's another problem.. Thanks

Comment: Projects like this seem to recommend using [bower](http://bower.io/) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) or similar which will usually take the pain out of including files. That said, the barrier to entry can be a little high if you've never used them before.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your html file, and then add your other `js` file(the one that will use the 1st js file) right after it.

Like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="1stfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="secondfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```